# Play store shows app crashes MyAppPackageName.MainActivity.onCreate androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, react-hooks, google-play

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyAppPackage/MyAppPackage.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3502)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3683)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2108)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:603)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:631)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:57)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:483)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager. (FragmentStateManager.java:85)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:2728)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:198)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$2.onContextAvailable (FragmentActivity.java:149)
> at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable (ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:322)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:273)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate (ReactActivity.java:45)
> at MyAppPackage.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:13)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8071)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8054)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3472)
> Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:343)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:613)
> Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Screen fragments should never be restored. Follow instructions from https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/17#issuecomment-<US_SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER> to properly configure your main activity.
> at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment. (ScreenFragment.kt:54)
> at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment. (ScreenStackFragment.kt:35)
>
> I checked app on multiple phones its working. But on play store I have more than 5000 reports of crashes in just few days. In recent build I just updated my targetSdkVersion from 31 to 34.
>
> my android build.gradlew is like this:
>
> buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
> minSdkVersion = 21
> compileSdkVersion = 31
> targetSdkVersion = 34
> kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue, I checked this issue and found that this issue is related to `react-native-screens` and I was missing one step from installation instructions.

You have to add below code in android/app/src/main/java//MainActivity.java in MainActivity class.

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
```

[You can check these instructions here.](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/17#issuecomment-424704067)